# Json.Convert return default values of an object created

Tags: c#, json.net

Suppose that I have a simple class called `Cat`, and I would like to serialize and deserialize this class

**Cat Class :**

```
 public class Cat {
   public Cat () : base (Type.Cat)
     { 
       this.Origin = "American";
       this.Color = "Black";
     }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Cat (bool Serialize) : base (Type.Cat) // base is Animal Class
     { 
      
     }
 }
```

**Animal Class :**

```
public class Animal
     public abstract class Animal {
       public string Color {
         get;
         set;
       }
       public string Origin {
         get;
         set;
       }
        public Animal(Type AnimalType)
         { 
            
         }
     }
```

**Serialize Method :**

```
   public void SerializeObj(Cat cat)
    {
        var mysettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto, 
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented };
    
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cat, typeof(Cat), mysettings );
    
                using (StreamWriter stream = new StreamWriter(path))
                {
                    stream.WriteLine(json);
                    stream.Close();
                }
    
    }
```

**Deserialize Method :**

```
 public object Deserialize(string object)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

        var cat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cat>(object, settings);

        return motor;

    }
```

**Called the two methods :**

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.Color = "White";
cat.Origin = "Europe";
var fileString = Serialize(cat);

// file created with fileString

Cat cat = Deserialize(myfile);
Console.WriteLine(cat.Origin); // it will print American
Console.WriteLine(cat.Color); // it will print black
```

The problem is that deserialize produce the default values not the values modified when serializing

***Note that myfile contains the updated values ( Color = "White" and Origin = "Europe")***

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Think the JSON inside yourFile (myFile :P) didn't deserialize to the class cat

Comment: What do you talking about?

Comment: Think the JSON in the intermediate file won't fit the expected format, that's why didnt serialize and the reason it hits the base constructor

Comment: No the JSON converter in other file

Comment: I did not mentioned the base class , the base class is Animal that is a simple class , I wouldn't like to write many pieces of code , I choose to write only important things

Comment: Please see updates

Comment: as I said before , I think  your JSON file din't have the "Serialize": true/false that the [JsonConstructor] is expecting, so he goes for the base constructor

Comment: Could you please a simple example of your solution?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Minimal, complete and verifiable please. We need to be able to follow all your steps

Comment: Code is still wrong: Animal class has no constructor accepting 1 argument

Comment: Can you post the real code pls? your code  can not be compiled

Comment: I edited my code and the code works for me only deserialization won't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code after fixing, since the code you posted can't be compiled.
Everything is working properly

```
void Main()
{
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    cat.Color = "White";
    cat.Origin = "Europe";
    var json = Serialize(cat);

     cat = Deserialize<Cat>(json);
    Console.WriteLine(cat.Origin); // it  printed Europe
    Console.WriteLine(cat.Color); // it printed White
}
```

methods

```
public string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    var mysettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
    };

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, mysettings);
}


 public T Deserialize<T>(string obj)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(obj, settings);
}
```

classes

```
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat () : base (AnimalType.Cat)
    {
        this.Origin = "American";
        this.Color = "Black";
    }
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Cat(bool Serialize) : base (AnimalType.Cat) {}
}

     public abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Color
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Origin
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Animal(AnimalType anymalType)
        {

        }
    }

public enum AnimalType
{
    Cat
}
```